# Deny access from browser to uploads folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm working on my own webpage. I got an uploads folder in which I am storing uploaded content like photos, pdf's, documents etc. I want to restrict access to that folder(disallow requests like 'http://www.mywebpage.com/uploads'). I tried to create .htacces file which contains '`Deny from all`' record. Now the access to that folder is restricted but other problem appears - all of the photos or other files are missing from my website. I guess, it's impossible to access them because of the .htaccess file.

Any suggestions?

I'm using WAMP with Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12 if that makes any sense.

Comment: easiest solution would be to upload an empty index.html file to the uploads folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to only deny access to directory listing of `www.yourpage.com/uploads`?
If so, try using:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
Options -Indexes
```

To prevent user to list the content of your uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

First create an `.htaccess` file inside your **uploads** folder.

Then add:

`Options -Indexes`

This will prevent directory listing, but you can still see the images by using the direct URL.

Something like this:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/photos/cute_cat.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

this is what I do on all of my websites:

I create a file called give_file.php

which grabs all the files from the folder which has restricted access and returns them to user.

```
//select access permissions from database. Then figure out if user is allowed to access it. if user is allowed to access it, set $allowed to 1;
if($allowed)
{

        $R=mysqli_query($Conn,'select * from users where resume=1 and id=' .$_REQUEST['uid']);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($R)==0)
        exit;
        $l=mysqli_fetch_assoc($R);
        $ln=$l['last_name'];
        $fn=$l['first_name'];
        $uniqueid=$l['uniqueid'];
        header("Content-type:application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='".$ln .'_' . $fn . "_resume.pdf'");
        readfile("resumes/resume_" . $uniqueid . '.pdf');



}
```

You can figure out what kind of headers you need for each image type. By doing this you can track all usage statistic, see if people are accessing site from somewhere else, and do all other kinds of interesting things.

Comment: That's complicated. All you need is just one `.htaccess` file and one line of code, And you're done. You don't need **13** lines of code to do that.

Comment: @Akar if you make a website and rely on **Options -Indexes** for security on documents that store social security numbers, credit cards or other sensitive information let me know.